# problema con la fecha javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con mi codigo javascript, mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una cuenta atras en javascript con la fecha pero no puedo colocar la fecha que esta como en el pc: osea la fecha para que funcione es la siguiente:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("2022-03-19").getTime();
```

lo que me gustaria es añadir bien la fecha de la siguiente manera

```
var countDownDate = new Date("19/03/2022").getTime();
```

Si le añado asi 19/03/2022 aparece NaNd NaNh NaNm NaNs

Este es mi codigo javascript:

```
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("2022-03-19").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: El formato de `Date` [debe ser uno reconocido por `Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), y como dice la [documentación en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse): _retorna `NaN` si la cadena no es reconocida o, en algunos casos, contiene valores de fecha ilegales (por ejemplo, 2015-02-31)_.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer una función de ayuda que te permita convertir la fecha de entrada en el formato `DD/MM/YYYY` a `YYYY-MM-DD`, podría ser algo así:

```js
function getDate(date) {
  const [day, month, year] = date.split('/');
  
  return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`).getTime();
}

console.log(getDate("19/03/2022"));
```

Con ayuda de la función split separas cada elemento divido por el caracter `/` y luego reordenas los elementos para pasar el formato requerido.